# PyGObject: Setting ComboBoxText's Active Text

Tags: python-3.x, pygobject

How can I set the active text of a ComboBoxText (with entry)?

There is no such method in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk

class App(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='ComboBoxEntry Test')

        model = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
        for i in [['One', '1'], ['Two', '2'], ['Three', '3'], ['Four', '4']]:
            model.append(i)

        combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText.new_with_entry()
        combo.set_model(model)

        #combo.set_active(0)
        combo.get_child().set_text('Five')

        self.add(combo)

win = App()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```